# iOS: push segue from UITableView, strange issue with tableView layout when clicked

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a `UITableView` and do `performSegueWithIdentifier` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method.

I am getting this weird bug. Well not sure if it is a bug. When I first open the `ViewController` with the `UITableView` everything looks fine (see picture 1 below). But when I click a row and it does the `push segue` it like graphically smashes the `row` upward (see picture 2).

When I click the back button from the pushed ViewController, it still stays smashed like that. Never seen this happen before. Why would it be happening?

[image]
[image]

**my code the ViewController that performs the segue**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showChatVC", sender: self)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    (appDelegate.getMenuTableVC() as MenuTableViewController).selectedMenuItem = 70
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showChatVC" {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as ChatViewController

        if let selectedItemIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row {
            vc.partnerUserId = idsWithMessages[selectedItemIndex]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious, did you implement an UIView animation on that card (with the cat on it) there?

Comment: @Somnibyte nope, no animations put anywhere on the VC.

Comment: Have you set the rowHeight property or implemented heightForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: For future reference, you can take screenshots in the Simulator using CMD+S.

Comment: @rdelmar Yes. The `rowHeight` property is set for the cell in the interface builder. But did not implement the `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Try setting the rowHeight property in viewDidLoad as well, and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @rdelmar I implemented `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and this fixed the problem. I also redid the constraints to make sure. If you make an answer I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try setting the rowHeight property instead? It's more efficient than implementing heightForRowAtIndexPath if all your cells have the same height.

Comment: @rdelmar Just used the `rowHeight` property in my `TableView` setup method. Much cleaner code! Thanks. I thought setting it in the `Interface Builder` was the same as setting it, but guess not?